# Javascript isn't doing arithmetic operations

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function with this code

```
total = parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2);
if(!$('#tablebody').is(':empty')){
                    $('#tablebody tr').each(function() {
                        total += parseFloat($(this).find('.subtotals').html()).toFixed(2);    
                    });
                }
```

But it isn't doing arithmetic operations instead it is giving me an output something like this `251.562500000.00250.00`. It just concatenates the numbers

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: toFixed converts it back to a string. Move the parseFloat end ) to after the toFixed

Comment: Does `.toFixed(2)` return a string?

Comment: It looks like the interpreter is getting Strings instead of Numbers. Try casting to a Number before you add to total.

Comment: @Blindman67 that won't work, since `.html()` returns a string that needs to be parsed before you can call `toFixed`.

Comment: @ssube Yep. Sorry was looking at the first line. Just wrap that line in `total += Number( ... )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, defeating your `parseFloat` call. Since `total` is already a string, the runtime has no qualms simply concatenating them.

To avoid cumulative rounding errors and ending up with a long string, save the `toFixed` call for the very end of your program.

```
total = parseFloat(subtotal);
if(!$('#tablebody').is(':empty')){
  $('#tablebody tr').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).find('.subtotals').html());    
  });
}
totalString = total.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.toFixed(2)` returns a formatted string with 2 decimal places.

Therefore, your `+` is just concatenating strings.

You don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

The toFixed function is converting them to string.  Strings behave by concatenating when encountering addition operators. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp